# Client-side variable with Rails/JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I think this should be very simple, but couldn't figure it out.

I'm trying to add some form fields with a click on button, but I have a limit, and each new field have to be numbered. So I must have a counter on the client side.

I'm stuck in a first step, I couldn't make a counter variable on the client-side. I'm pretty sure my code isn't executing, because i don't even get the "loaded" message.

But I've no clue why my javscript isn't working. I get the following error on console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addQuickReply is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

When I add the function to buyers.coffee the function:

```
@addQuickReply = (counter) ->
  alert("counter is:"+counter)
```

I get this alert:

```
counter is:undefined
```

## /views/buyers/answer.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h3>Responder <%= @buyer.name %></h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" id="quick-button">
      <%= link_to 'Quick Reply', load_form_path(id: @buyer.id, type: "quick"), method: :post,
                    remote: true %>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div id="form-container">
  </div>

</div>
```

## /views/buyers/load_form.js.erb.html

```
document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = '<%= j render(@type) %>';
```

## /views/buyers/_quick.html.erb

```
</br>
<%= javascript_include_tag "load_quick_reply" %>
<%= form_tag("/answers/quick", method: "post", class: "form-horizontal") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag("type", "quick") %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag("buyer_id", @buyer.id) %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Texto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= text_field_tag(:text,nil, class: "form-control") %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="replies">
    <%= render partial: 'quick_each', locals: {number: 0} %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addQuickReply()">New Reply</a>
        <%= submit_tag("Enviar" , role: "button", class: "btn btn-info" ) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("loaded");
   var counter=0;
   var container = document.getElementById("replies");
   function addQuickReply(){
     counter++;
     alert("counter is :"+counter);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is backend js is frontend, youre trying to make a rails variable receive something from front, you cant do that you could send something from back end to front.

So in your code , this must pass a paramether as counter for your js function:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addQuickReply(params)">New Reply</a>
```

this must be, this way:

```
addQuickReply = (counter) ->
alert("counter is:"+counter)
```

the error is shown because you're not creating a js function.

I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: I think my problem is related to the remote execution of code and update of the page. For some reason (I don't know if this was expected to happen), only the JS files an functions loaded with the page at first are able to execute. The problem is that the script was inside a partial that is loaded inside a div after a click on a button. This code does not execute. Any clue about this?